# How to parse this json data?

Tags: ajax, json

Can anyone please explain me how can I parse below json response .

**this is my function**

```
function supplierBelongings() {
            $.getJSON('accountpayble_getDataOnSuplierForInvoiceAdd.action', function(data) {
                alert(data);
                var data1 = data[0], data2 = data[1];
                alert(data1);
                alert(data2);
//                alert(data.currency.currencyName);
                //var splitVar = data.split(","); 
                //var data1 = data[0], data2 = data[1];
//                alert(splitVar[0]);
//                alert(splitVar[1]);
            });
        }
```

**This is my response**

```
 bothJson = [{"exchangeRateId":1,"currency":{"currencyId":1,"currencyName":"India","currencyCode":"INR","currencySymbol":"$","currencyDescription":"acfsf","currencySymbolPlace":"dvd"},"exchangeRateEffectiveDate":"Oct 18, 2014","exchangeRateValue":"20"},{"currencyId":1,"currencyName":"India","currencyCode":"INR","currencySymbol":"$","currencyDescription":"acfsf","currencySymbolPlace":"dvd"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's parse JSON

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( bothJson);
alert( obj.exchangeRateId === 1 );
```

If you are more specific on which value you want I can help drill down from here.